# ng serve, ERROR in metadata version mismatch

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm trying to update from Angular 4 to 5, but I think I may be messing up my package.json since I'm getting the following error upon trying to execute ng serve:

```
ERROR in Metadata version mismatch for module C:/path/gui/src/app/app.module.ts, found version 3, expected 4
```

The reason I'm using version 5.1.1 below is because I kept getting a separate issue that was resolved here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21621

Here's my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "newton",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "Proprietary",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint --exclude \"**/node_modules/**\"",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.1.1",
    "@angular/common": "5.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "5.1.1",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "2.0.0-beta.10-4905443",
    "@angular/forms": "5.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "5.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "5.1.1",
    "core-js": "2.5.3",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "mydatepicker": "^2.0.20",
    "ng2-stomp-service": "^1.2.2",
    "ng2-translate": "5.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.6",
    "sockjs-client": "^1.1.4",
    "stompjs": "^2.3.3",
    "wijmo": "wijmo-system-min",
    "zone.js": "0.8.20"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "2.6.2"
  }
}
```

And here's my app.module.ts:

```
/*


import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule, Http } from '@angular/http';

import { DashboardComponent } from './components/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { MaintenanceComponent } from './components/maintenance/maintenance.component';
import { AcquisitionComponent } from './components/acquisition/acquisition.component';
import { AlarmsAlertsService } from './shared/notification-manager.service';
import { SlideManagerService } from './shared/slide-manager.service';
import { AuditService, Logger } from './shared/log.service';
import { AuthGuard } from './shared/auth-guard.service';
import { AuthService } from './shared/auth.service';
import { ConfigurationComponent } from './components/configuration/configuration.component';
import { ConfirmService } from './shared/confirm/confirm.service';
import { PopOverComponent } from './shared/pop-over/pop-over.component';
import { InstrumentStatusService } from './shared/notification-manager.service';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { ReportsComponent } from './components/reports/reports.component';
import { MyDatePickerModule } from 'mydatepicker/dist/my-date-picker.module';
import { MyDatePickerComponent } from './shared/date-picker/my-date-picker.component';
import { RestClientService } from './shared/rest-client.service';
import { SearchComponent } from './components/search/search.component';
import { SupervisionComponent } from './components/supervision/supervision.component';
import { TranslateModule, TranslateStaticLoader, TranslateLoader } from 'ng2-translate';
import { HelpComponent } from './components/help/help.component';
import { ConfirmComponent } from './shared/confirm/confirm.component';
import { InteractiveSlideComponent } from './components/interactive-slide/interactive-slide.component';
import { SlidesTableComponent } from './components/slides-table/slides-table.component';
import { VolumeControlComponent } from './components/volume-control/volume-control.component';
import { SortArrowsComponent } from './components/sort-arrows/sort-arrows.component';
import { StatusIndicatorComponent } from './components/status-indicator/component-status-indicator.component';
import { TabComponent } from './components/tab/tab.component';
import { TabsComponent } from './components/tabs/tabs.component';
import { WjGridModule } from 'wijmo/wijmo.angular2.grid';
import { UiSwitchComponent } from './shared/ui-switch/ui-switch.component';
import { FocusDirective } from './shared/date-picker/directives/my-date-picker.focus.directive';
import { MyErrorHandlerService } from './shared/error/handle-error.service';
import { StompService } from 'ng2-stomp-service';

export function createTranslateLoader(http: Http) {
    return new TranslateStaticLoader(http, './assets/i18n', '.json');
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
      AcquisitionComponent,
      ConfigurationComponent,
      ConfirmComponent,
      MyDatePickerComponent,
      PopOverComponent,
      DashboardComponent,
      MaintenanceComponent,
      HelpComponent,
      InteractiveSlideComponent,
      LoginComponent,
      ReportsComponent,
      SearchComponent,
      SlidesTableComponent,
      SortArrowsComponent,
      StatusIndicatorComponent,
      SupervisionComponent,
      TabComponent,
      TabsComponent,
      VolumeControlComponent,
      FocusDirective,
      UiSwitchComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    WjGridModule,
    MyDatePickerModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
        deps: [Http]
    }),
    WjGridModule
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    AcquisitionComponent,
    ConfigurationComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    ReportsComponent,
    SearchComponent,
    SupervisionComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    AuditService,
    AlarmsAlertsService,
    AuthGuard,
    AuthService,
    ConfirmService,
    InstrumentStatusService,
    Logger,
    RestClientService,
    StompService,
    SlideManagerService,
    { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: MyErrorHandlerService }
  ],
  bootstrap: [DashboardComponent],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Getting `@angular/compiler-cli` up to version 5.1.1 would be a good start. There will likely be other version mismatch errors after that. Work through them one by one.

Comment: angular-cli 1.0.0 is really, really old now. The current stable version is 1.7.3. Upgrade to the latest version. See https://github.com/cexbrayat/angular-cli-diff/compare/1.0.0...1.7.3 for all the changes in a new project between 1.0.0 and 1.7.3